# If $f$ is bijection in a dense subset then $f$ is bijection in all space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X=(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ and $Y=(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological Hausdorff spaces and $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous function. If $f:D \subset X \longrightarrow Y$, with $D$ dense in $X$, is a bijection (one-to-one and onto) then $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ is a bijection too.

This is true in general?

Comment: Doesn’t look like it. For each $y\in Y$, there is some $x\in D$ such that $f(x) = y$. That means that for each $x^\prime\in X\setminus D$ there is an $x\in D$ for which $f(x)=f(x^\prime)$, so $f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general, and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces (or that $D$ is dense in $X$ and $f$ is continuous) is not relevant to the question.

Suppose that $D$ is a strict subset of $X$. Since $f\vert_D$ is onto, we have that for each $y\in Y$, there is some $x\in D$ such that $f(x) = y$. Then, for each $x^\prime\in X\setminus D$, we have that there is some $x\in D$ so that $f(x) = f(x^\prime)$.

This implies that $f$ is not injective.

More generally, Take any two sets $X$ and $Y$, and a function $f\colon X\to Y$ whose restriction $f\vert_D \colon D\to Y$, where $D\subsetneq X$ is a strict subset, is surjective. Then, $f$ cannot be injective.

However, this also helps one see that if $D = X$, then, trivially, the claim is true.

Comment: But what if the statement of the question forces $D = X$?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Good point. I meant to say it is not true in general. :) I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Let me clarify: Suppose that whenever the assumptions of the question hold, it follows that $D = X$. If that's the case, then the statement *is* true in general. I don't have a proof or counterexample yet. Just wondering.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Good question. Let's see. Suppose $X$ is a two-point set with the Sierpinski topology, and $Y$ be a discrete one-point set. I think I can choose a continuous $f$ whose restriction to a dense subset of $X$ is a bijection, but I'll need a pen and paper to work through the details.

Comment: Oh wait, Sierpinski is not Hausdorff.

Comment: $X$ is not Hausdorff in this example; is it?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes, already acknowledged. :)

Comment: Sorry, your comment came in as I posted mine.

Comment: @AymanHourieh No worries. I think you might be right, actually, that the assumptions imply that $D=X$. Though, I have no proof.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I am thinking about the following example. Let $X$ be locally-compact (but not compact) and Hausdorff, and let $Y = X$. Then $X$ is dense in its one-point compactification $X^*$. I wonder if there is a way to extend the identity map on $X$ to a continuous map on $X^*$?

Comment: I think I found a counterexample. It turned out to be simpler than I thought. Feel free to have a look at the answer I added.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice extreme example. Let $X$ be any set with at least two elements and fix $x\in X$ to be one of them. Consider the topology $\{\varnothing\}\cup\{A\mid x\in A\}$.

Now let $Y$ be *any* topological space, and fix $y\in Y$. Now consider the constant function $f(u)=y$ for all $u\in X$. This function is a bijection on the dense set $\{x\}$, since any function is injective on a singleton, and it is continuous since if $U$ is any open set, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is either empty or $X$, both of which are open. But $f$ is far from a bijection.

Comment: Cool example, but I think it is not Hausdorff?

Comment: $X$ is not Hausdorff in this counterexample. The question seems to suggest that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: I guess I understood "in general" differently...

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: I don't know, good question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample in which $X$ is Hausdorff:

Consider the continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to S^1$ given by $t \mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$. It's not bijective, since $f(0) = f(1)$. Yet, $[0, 1)$ is dense in $[0, 1]$ and the restriction of $f$ to $[0, 1)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Ah, yes, this sounds similar in spirit to the one I was trying to think about. Thanks for letting me know about it.